# How to perform SHAP explainer on a system of models

Tags: scikit-learn, keras, autoencoders, boosting, shapley-value

I have developed a model with Autoencoder + XGBoost. Autoencoder is used to reduce dimensionality and then passed on to XGBoost for prediction. I would like to understand the feature importance of the root variables in the prediction.

SHAP on XGBoost is giving me the importance of encoded variables from AE. Is there a way to treat these two models together as a system of models and perform SHAP on top of both of these to retrieve feature importance of the raw variable?

Comment: There is a lot of acronyms there! Can you explain/link?

Comment: Can you be more precise about what code do you use ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the comments. I was able to figure out the error. Now everything is working fine. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SHAP offers a model-agnostic shapley-value estimator:
https://github.com/slundberg/shap/blob/master/README.md#model-agnostic-example-with-kernelexplainer-explains-any-function

You just need to wrap the AE/xgb prediction pipeline into a single predict_proba function for the first argument to `KernelExplainer`.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response. I tried doing that but getting some weird error.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code:

```
explainer = shap.KernelExplainer(predict_call, dat_testing.Xt().sample(100)) #Pandas DataFrame
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(dat_testing.Xt(), nsamples=100)
```

Getting this error:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

When running the function out of the KernelExplainer it is running fine.